# SharePoint CSOM crashes IIS App pool

Tags: development, csom, mvc, online

What I’m trying to achieve here is a MVC website that gets some info from SharePoint. I did that on VS 2017, works perfectly.

This is the code:

```
        var ctx = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://MYSITEURL");

        //using auto connect
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        User user = web.CurrentUser;
        ctx.Load(web);
        ctx.Load(user);
        //ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        ViewBag.Site += web.Title;
```

Inside VS 2017 it works without any errors, on the remote host that ive got set up I get `503 Service Unavailable` and it seems like its crashing the App Pool that I’ve for this web app.

My question is: Is there something wrong with using the code as I'm using it or is my IIS simply not configured correctly (first time configuring that annoying thing).

Edit: Just checked the logs, this is what shows up when the app pool crashes:

```
StackTrace:    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
at OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<GetWebLoginClientContext>b__0()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Is this from SharePoint PnP Core library <OfficeDevPnP.Core>?

Comment: Yep, im using that one. The error is somewhat related (i suppose?), but still no idea whats the problem exactly.

Comment: It seems that it tries to open a win32 window for authenticating the user. I don’t think that this approach is valid for web app.

Comment: Yep, `System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog` is key here. That is an application window and you should expect the App Pool to crash.

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to change the code so it works as an MVC ? (pretty new to c# here, still learning)